# cannot use make([]Entry, 0, 100) (type []Entry) as type Map in assignment

Tags: arrays, dictionary, go, slice

Trying to implement go map, with below code:

```
package gomap

type Entry struct {
    stockName  string
    stockValue float64
}

type Bucket []Entry

type Map [4]Bucket

type bucketElementPosition [4]int

var emptyPosition = bucketElementPosition{0, 0, 0, 0}

func Newmap() Map {

    return Map{} // [(nil,0,0), (nil,0,0), (nil,0,0), (nil,0,0)]
}

func Insert(m []Map, key string, value float64) { // m is sliceofslices type

    bucketNumber := (key[0] - 'A') / 7

    if cap(m[bucketNumber]) == 0 { // first insert, so create the backing array
        m[bucketNumber] = make([]Entry, 0, 100)
    }
}
```

---

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/myhub/cs61a/gomap"
)

func main() {

    var stockData = gomap.Newmap()
    gomap.Insert(stockData[:], "AAPL", 94.56)

}
```

---

`m[bucketNumber] = make([]Entry, 0, 100)` gives error:

```
     cannot use make([]Entry, 0, 100) (type []Entry) as type Map in assignment
```

---

How to pass slice header of `stockData` to `Insert()` function?

Comment: GIven that `v := expr` declares a new *variable* `v`, what *new variable* did you expect to be declared here? The only variable name is `m`. Did you want a whole new `m`?

Comment: @torek Sorry, my bad, it is assignment. Query edited

Comment: Slicing an array gives a slice having *element type* identical to the *array element type*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Using a pointer to `Map`

`m` is of type `[]Map`, so `m[bucketNumber]` will be of type `Map`, not `bucket`.

Change type of `m` to `*Map` and dereference when used:

```
func Insert(m *Map, key string, value float64) { // m is sliceofslices type
    bucketNumber := (key[0] - 'A') / 7

    if cap((*m)[bucketNumber]) == 0 { // first insert, so create the backing array
        (*m)[bucketNumber] = make([]Entry, 0, 100)
    }
}
```

And pass the address of `stockData`:

```
gomap.Insert(&stockData, "AAPL", 94.56)
```

Alhtough note that arrays in Go are secondary. The code would be simpler and probably more efficient if you'd use slices instead of arrays (and pointer to arrays).

#### Exporting `bucket` and using `[]Bucket`

If you can export `bucket`, then you can change type of `m` to `[]Bucket`:

```
func Insert(m []Bucket, key string, value float64) { // m is sliceofslices type
    bucketNumber := (key[0] - 'A') / 7

    if cap(m[bucketNumber]) == 0 { // first insert, so create the backing array
        m[bucketNumber] = make([]Entry, 0, 100)
    }
}
```

And call it like:

```
Insert(stockData[:], "AAPL", 94.56)
```

Comment: When I pass `stockData[:]`, am I not passing a new slice header of 24 bytes i.e., (pointer,4,4) where `pointer` points to `stockData`?

Comment: @overexchange I don't know what `gomap.Newmap()` is, it's not a public repo.

Comment: Sorry, the code is in the query: `func Newmap() Map {..}`. public repo? I didn't get you

Comment: @overexchange `NewMap()` returns a `Map`, you just have to pass that as-is.

Comment: Passing array will create a new copy, which is not good. So am passing `stockData[:]`

Comment: @overexchange Oh, I see what you mean / want now. Please see edited answer.

Comment: With poinnter it is working but, I want to practice with sliceofslice `[][]Map`, because am new to Go. Does it make sense to try `[][]Map` instead of `*Map`?

Comment: @overexchange But `bucket` is an unexported type, so you can't refer to it. If it would be exported, you could do that.

Comment: Exported type `type Bucket []Entry` and `type Map [4]Bucket` doesn't solve the problem. I see the same error

Comment: @overexchange See edited answer how to make it work with exported `Bucket`.

Comment: But we are actually passing slice header of `Map{}` value, when we say `stockData[:]`.  How `[]Bucket` type can accept slice header of `Map{}`? Am confused...

Comment: @overexchange `Map` is a type having `[4]Bucket` as its underlying type, so `stockData[:]` is of type `[]Bucket`, it's not a `[]Map`. `Map` is an array, there is no such thing as _"slice header of `Map`"_. Slices have slice header, but `Map` is not a slice type, it's an array type. Slicing an array gives a slice having element type identical to the array element type.

Comment: @overexchange If `Map` would be `[4][]Entry`, `Insert` would be like: `Insert(m [][]Entry, key string, value float64)` and you would call it like `Insert(stockData[:], "AAPL", 94.56)`.

Comment: "Slicing an array gives a slice having element type identical to the array element type" I tried understanding your line with this [code](https://github.com/shamhub/firstapp/blob/master/src/github.com/shamhub/cs61a/Main.go#L9).  Does `stockData[:]` create a new slice header(pointer,4,4) that points to `stockData`?

Comment: Yes, `stockData[:]` will be a slice header having `stockData` as its backing array. Changing elements of the result slice will change the array elements.